# is it right to use "the" before " variety" as bellow? and why?

Tags: grammar

It is undeniable that only by visiting isolated natural places do people comprehend more deeply about how **the** variety of strange creatures survive and grow in the scope of their own environments.

Comment: The sentence is poorly constructed.

Answer (score 1):

It is proposed that only by visiting isolated natural places do people comprehend more deeply the variety of strange creatures that survive and grow within the scope of an environment.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're talking about various different types of environments, or an unspecified number of environments, each of which has its own set of strange creatures, so you should say "**a** variety of strange creatures".

The reason you should avoid using "the" in this case is because you're not referring to "variety" as a particular thing, but only as a generic modifier of the word "creatures". For example, you would say "I like **the** variety of animals in this zoo" but "There is **a** variety of animals in this zoo." In the first case, you are focusing specifically on the variety, whereas in the second case, you're focusing on the animals.

Here are your two options:

"how **a** variety of strange creatures survive and grow in their own environments": the creatures are the subject, and they're not a specific entity, thus "a variety".

"how **the** variety of strange creatures survive**s** and grow**s** in **its** own **environment**": the variety is the subject, and it's a specific variety in a specific environment, thus "the variety".

Also FYI, you don't need to use "about" with the verb "comprehend". So your sentence should say "people comprehend more deeply how ..."

Comment: Thank you very much for your detail explanation, it is very useful for me